# Pushing changes to production github of Next.js repo

Tags: node.js, next.js, vercel, dev-to-production, next.js13

I'm not a react/node developper but I have a **Next.js** website where **I made some minor changes (CSS + Javascript) but they are not showing on the production URL**.

How I proceeded :

**Step1:** I run the local repo with 'npm run dev' and made changes using my IDE that appear on localhost 8080

**Step2:** I add/push the changes to the repo's master branch that is deployed with Vercel (with a domain) but they do not show.

step3: I also checked on localhost:3000 with 'npm run build && npm start' , changes are showing up locally

**How can I proceed/resolve the issue ?**

If someone can help also , the command next start is not working in the directory

many thanx